# XPath: How can I get all nodes with specific path suffix?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath

I have next xml-file (E://testHtmlFile.html):

```
<bookstore>
    <anyA>
        <anyB>
            <book>
                <title lang="end">Harry Potter</title>
                <price>29.99</price>
            </book>
        </anyB>
        <book>
            <title lang="era">Learning XML</title>
            <price>39.95</price>
        </book>
    </anyA>
</bookstore>
```

I need to get all elements inside tags anyB/book with lang="e...", there is one:

```
<title lang="end">Harry Potter</title>
```

For this purpose I use next xpath string:

```
"//anyB/book/*[@lang[starts-with(., 'e')]]"
```

but it don't return any element. What is wrong?

My Python program:

```
from lxml.html import document_fromstring

with open ("E://testHtmlFile.html", "r") as myfile:
    html=myfile.read()  
tree = document_fromstring(html)
books = tree.xpath("//anyB/book/*[@lang[starts-with(., 'e')]]") 
outStr="";
for curBook in books:
    outStr= outStr+curBook.text+"\n"
outputRes=open("E:\\out.txt", 'w+');
print(outStr,file=outputRes)
```

If replace tag

```
<anyB>
```

by

```
<other>
```

then my program work fine.
It looks like a problem with letter registers...

Comment: XPath seem to be correct. What tool do you use?

Comment: It's not your XPath/XML that's wrong, so you'll need to post the Python code you're using and the results you're seeing in order to get further help.